# undefined reference to 'readline'

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm trying to use the readline library in my `c++` project using `netbeans`, so I've installed libreadline6-dev and add it to my project Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library directories -> and add (usr/include/readline).

But while compiling I get this error : `undefined reference to 'readline'.`

I found that I need to add also -lreadline to somewhere, but I have no idea where to put it.

Any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: (I removed the java tag, since this has nothing to do with Java, apart from that Netbeans is written in Java.)

Comment: I did that just to have more viewers ;)

Comment: That is inconsiderate, to say the least.  People who follow the [java] and [c#] tags do so because the are interested in questions about Java and C#.  You might have gotten a few extra people to view this question, but those people are almost certainly not the people who can actually answer it:  the people who can answer it already follow the [c++] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the good way, the problem you got is about the linker.

You have to specify the library(readline) here:

Project properties -> Build -> Linker -> Libraries.

and you also need to specify the path of the library:

Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library directories

But, like nos said, it is not the include directory.The include directory is the headers of the library(.h).

The linker needs a file with the extension .a on UNIX, it should be under a lib directory (ex: /usr/lib depends on where the library is installed).

If it is not working be sure that the file [library_directory]/libreadline.a exists

You also need to link ncurses with your project because readline uses it.