# undefined reference to `readline'

Tags: c, readline, libreadline

I'm having a problem trying to run the [GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library sample code [available in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline#Sample_code). Here it goes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main()
{
    char* input, shell_prompt[100];

    // Configure readline to auto-complete paths when the tab key is hit.
    rl_bind_key('\t', rl_complete);

    for(;;) {
        // Create prompt string from user name and current working directory.
        snprintf(shell_prompt, sizeof(shell_prompt), "%s:%s $ ", getenv("USER"), getcwd(NULL, 1024));

        // Display prompt and read input (n.b. input must be freed after use)...
        input = readline(shell_prompt);

        // Check for EOF.
        if (!input)
            break;

        // Add input to history.
        add_history(input);

        // Do stuff...

        // Free input.
        free(input);
    }
}
```

I'm working on a restricted environment were readline was not available, so I had to download the sources, compile it and install it to my home dir.

This is the structure inside my home directory:

```
.local
├── include
│   └── readline
│       ├── chardefs.h
│       ├── history.h
│       ├── keymaps.h
│       ├── readline.h
│       ├── rlconf.h
│       ├── rlstdc.h
│       ├── rltypedefs.h
│       └── tilde.h
└── lib
    ├── libhistory.a
    ├── libhistory.so -> libhistory.so.6
    ├── libhistory.so.6 -> libhistory.so.6.2
    ├── libhistory.so.6.2
    ├── libreadline.a
    ├── libreadline.so -> libreadline.so.6
    ├── libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.2
    └── libreadline.so.6.2
```

The problem is, when I call gcc it throws me an error:

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello_c.o -I /home/my-home-dir/.local/include
/tmp/cckC236E.o: In function `main':
hello.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `rl_complete'
hello.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `rl_bind_key'
hello.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `readline'
hello.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `add_history'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is an answer about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928203/undefined-reference-to-readline), but I'm not using Netbeans and I'm not quite sure how to specify the path to the library on the command line.

I tried to tell the linker where the libraries are, but the result is still the same:

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello_c.o -I /home/my-home-dir/.local/include -Xlinker "-L /home/my-home-dir/.local/lib"
/tmp/cceiePMr.o: In function `main':
hello.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `rl_complete'
hello.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `rl_bind_key'
hello.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `readline'
hello.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `add_history'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: You need to link the library, so put `-lreadline` near the end of your `gcc` command (and probably `-L.local/lib` before). And to get a `*.o` out of a `*.c` use  `gcc -Wall -c -g hello.c -o hello.o`

Comment: use -ledit for readline and add_history

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to link against the actual library using `-lreadline` in gcc arguments.